# Scrapy: How parse multiple pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have an initial link from which I get the number of pages. How to get the url of the start link?

Pagination does not work:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/&pageNum=2> (referer: https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/usearch?where=CA&sessionId=%7BsessionId%7D&requestId=%7BrequestId%7D&sort.provider=bestmatch&source=init&what=%7Bspecialty%7D&category=provider&cid&debug=false&debugParams=false&isPsr=false&isFsr=false&isFirstRequest=true&userLocalTime=23%3A55)
```

spider:

```
def start_requests(self): 
    yield scrapy.Request('https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/usearch?where=CA&sessionId={sessionId}&requestId={requestId}' +
                                 '&sort.provider=bestmatch&source=init&what={specialty}&category=provider&cid&debug=false&d' + 
                                 'ebugParams=false&isPsr=false&isFsr=false&isFirstRequest=true&userLocalTime=23%3A55', 
                                  callback=self.pagination)

def pagination(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    totalPages = jsonresponse['search']['searchResults']['totalPages']

    for page in range(1, totalPages):
        page = '&pageNum=%s' % page  
        yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.request.url, page), callback=self.profile_link)
```

Comment: What’s wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Gallaecio I updated my question

Comment: I think your issue is using `urljoin` to change a URL query string parameter. I suggest you use `w3lib.url.add_or_replace_parameter` to build the URL of the next pages.